# ajax loading problem

Tags: html, ajax

i had a theme changer in ajax made and it worked fine, i changed my domain and i cant figure out why it wont do what it did befor, the scripts i cant see anything that would make a domain name change affect it:

the website: `chat-rage.com`
the script: `chat-rage.com/Script_Files/slider.js`
the other script: `chat-rage.com/Script_Files/jquery.min.js`

the main nav bar that changes the themes is the pic that says network of themes

view sorce of page

and the menu that drops down is called "network of themes"

and it has the proper links on them it works, it ends up blank, it should change them to the applets like it did before.

any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post some sort of working (or not) example of this? A website URL or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) example? That would help loads.

Comment: i dont have a working example, i had this made by a proggramer that charged me out the butt for it, but it was working, only thing i changed was the domain from http://bioprotege-inc.sytes.net to http://bioprotege-inc.net and the applet style from html to dhtml, but thats the data that gets placed in the spots that wouldn't affect much.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be a cross-domain issue. Ajax calls will not work if the source and target domains do not match. For instance, if your site is at chat-rage.com, but the ajax is loading from server1.bioprotege-inc.net, it's not going to work.

You'll want to look into using jsonp instead of plain ajax. If you are using jQuery (which it looks like you are), jsonP support is offered via its ajax methods.

Comment: it worked befor , i had chat rage.com and befor that i had my ip as http://bioprotege-inc.sytes.net, but i changed that to http://bioprotege-inc.net, same dns type service went from no-ip to godaddy and used dyndns service instead so i cant see that being a problem